# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a java.util.Collection or Array

Tags: dxa

I am getting the below exception since morning. This is thrown in the generic main Controller that we have written at line `getPageModel(requestPath, localization);` This exception occurs on all the pages. I am eliminating each include page at a time but no luck.

> **Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException:** null   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.buildRegions(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.PageBuilder.createPage(PageBuilder.java:141)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TContentProvider$1.tryFindPage(DD4TContentProvider.java:83)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TContentProvider$1.tryFindPage(DD4TContentProvider.java:69)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TContentProvider.findPage(DD4TContentProvider.java:135)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TContentProvider.getPageModel(DD4TContentProvider.java:69)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.PageBuilder.createPage(PageBuilder.java:134)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TContentProvider$1.tryFindPage(DD4TContentProvider.java:83)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TContentProvider$1.tryFindPage(DD4TContentProvider.java:69)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TContentProvider.findPage(DD4TContentProvider.java:135)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TContentProvider.getPageModel(DD4TContentProvider.java:69)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.addon.controller.GenericMainController.getPageModel(GenericMainController.java:161)
>   ~[GenericMainController.class:na]     ... 53 common frames omitted Caused
>   by: **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null   a**t
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_79]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_79]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_79]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.api.DefaultImplementation.invoke(DefaultImplementation.java:36)
>   ~[common-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]   ... 65 common frames
>   omitted **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a
>   java.util.Collection or Array     at**
>   org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.assertCollectionOrArray(TypeDescriptor.java:597)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.getElementTypeDescriptor(TypeDescriptor.java:431)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.fieldconverters.EmbeddedFieldConverter.getFieldValue(EmbeddedFieldConverter.java:41)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TSemanticFieldDataProvider.getFieldData(DD4TSemanticFieldDataProvider.java:83)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl$1.doWith(SemanticMapperImpl.java:68)
>   ~[common-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:577)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:554)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:47)
>   ~[common-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.EntityBuilder.createEntity(EntityBuilder.java:81)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.PageBuilder$DD4TRegionBuilderCallback.buildEntity(PageBuilder.java:84)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder.buildRegions(DefaultRegionBuilder.java:44)
>   ~[common-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]  ... 70 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: Is this the latest DXA version? DXA 1.2 with JAVA is released now. This is the first DXA release with JAVA support. You might be using an older development copy. https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/m/mediagallery/1241

Comment: Indeed, the stack trace indicates that you are on a pre-release version. We don't keep track of the source code for these pre-release versions. But you will probably have the source code (which you used to compile that version).  I suggest to check what is on line 41 of `EmbeddedFieldConverter.java` to get a better idea of how it is failing.

Comment: Line 41 shows        `final TypeDescriptor elementType = targetType.getElementTypeDescriptor();`

Comment: I was able to find which model caused this issue. It was because I allowed multiple values on a link on the Schema level but didn't handle it in the model side in Java. Thanks for pointing me to the correct line.

Comment: @Rache. Great you found the problem. You can add the answer to your own question here on Tridion.Stackexchange and approve your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue came up because I allowed multiple values on a link field on the schema level in CMS but forgot to modify the model in Java. This caused the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a java.util.Collection or Array exception.